# Passing a NULL reference pointer to another class's function for memory allocation

Tags: c++, pointers, pass-by-reference

I have 2 classes, Class A and Class B.

From A::fun1(), I am trying pass a NULL pointer as reference to B::fun2(). I want B::fun2() to dynamically allocate memory to my reference pointer and give it back to Class A.

My program crashes when I try to do so. However when I allocate memory in Class A and pass it to B, everything works.

Is it not possible to pass a Null pointer as reference to another class and get it back with some memory allocated to it ?

Below is the code that I tried.

Struct X:

```
struct X
{
    char symbol;
    uint32_t number;
};
```

Class A:

```
class A
{
    public:
        A();
        void fnA();
        void printA();

    private:
        X*  _objAx;
};

A::A():
   _objAx(0)
{ }

void
A::fnA()
{
    //_objAx = new X();   //<---- Uncommenting this line make the program work.
    B::create(this,
              _objAx);    // Passing the NULL pointer as reference
}

void
A::printA()
{
    cout << "Sym: " << _objAx->symbol << "; Num: " << _objAx->number << endl;
}
```

Class B:

```
class B
{
    public:
        static void create(A*   pObjA,
                           X*   &objX);
        void fnB();

    private:
        B(A* pObjA, X* &objX);

        A*  _pObjA;
        X*  _objBx;
};

B::B(A*     pObjA,
     X*&    objX):
   _pObjA(pObjA),         // Pointer to Class A in order to call A::printA() later
   _objBx(objX)           // The NULL pointer got from Class A
{   }

void
B::create(A*    pObjA,
          X*&   objX)
{
    B* obB = new B(pObjA,
                   objX);

    obB->fnB();
}

void
B::fnB()
{
    // Commenting out the below line and doing memory allocation in Class A, 
    // makes the program work.
    _objBx = new X();   

    _objBx->symbol = 'p';
    _objBx->number = 30;
    // Following line crashes the program
    _pObjA->printA();
}
```

Main:

```
int main()
{
    A *ob = new A();
    ob->fnA();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `X*  _objBx` not a reference.

Comment: The semantics here are really complex, can it not be simplified? OT rather than use an *out parameter* consider *returning* a `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: You never assign your `new B()` object to anything other than a local pointer which dissappears after the `B::create()` function ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_objBx = new X();` in the `B` member function, modifies the `B::_objBx` object. This is nothing to do with any `A::_objAx;`.

Then `pObjA->printA();` calls a function which dereferences a null pointer.

I am guessing from your description that you intended `B` to contain `X*  &_objBx;` member instead.

Comment: Thanks. Missing to make _objBx a reference.